# Ввод и вывод строки

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char f;
    scanf_s("%s",&f);
    printf("%s",f);
}
```

Хочу считать с клавиатуры строку и вывести её. Выводится <null>. Что я делаю не так?
UPD А как должно быть на Си?

Comment: Где вы вообще здесь C++ увидели?

Comment: @deterok судя по примеру человек пишет первый в жизни HelloWorld. Вы полагаете, что на данном этапе обучения он обязан знать о шаблонах, классах, исключениях и всем том, что отличает С++ от чистого Си?

Comment: @DreamChild Со стандартными I/O потоками знакомят вначале большинства учебных материалов.

Comment: Ну а ему-то откуда знать, что его код  не использует возможности с++?  Учитывая, что для компилятора с++ код вполне корректен

Comment: Только вот (scanf("%s", ...) или scanf_s("%s", ...)) это чтение **не строки**, а *слова*, т.е. функция пропустит в потоке ввода "пробелы" (включая табуляции, перевод строки и т.п.) и введет следующие за ними символы, до "пробела".

Например, для ввода

   abc def
   

в переменную Вы прочтете "abc", а не "abc def", что следовало бы ожидать, если хотели прочитать строку.

Для чтения строки используйте, например `fgets`, вот ее прототип:

    char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);

Comment: Да, вы правы, с Си я работаю второй раз в жизни. Спасибо за все комментарии, они очень полезны.

Comment: @Dazar, в обновлении вопроса Вы спрашиваете, как писать на Си?

Очень просто, в принципе можно написать 

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int main () {
      char buf[1024];
      while (puts("Enter line :", fflush(stdout), 
             fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
          buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;
          printf ("Line is: [%s]\n", buf);
      }
      return puts("Bye !") == EOF;
    }

так, что С++ тоже принимает за свое.

Транслировал gcc и g++ в ubuntu.

Новые вопросы лучше задавайте, открывая новую тему (здесь не чат!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если хотите читать строку, так обявляйте строку, а не символ.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char f[1024]; // 1024 символа думаю хватит на первое время
    scanf_s("%s",&f); // вообще то это майкрософтовская поделка,
    // а не нормальная функция, но пусть будет она.
    printf("%s",f);
}
```

Comment: Скопировал Ваш код, ничего вообще не выводит...
Может у меня проблемы с компилятором?

Comment: что бы оно что то вывело, нужно для начала что-то ввести.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну конечно же я что-то ввожу. Ввёл "abcd", нажал ентер, вывелось только "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу.."

Comment: Посмотрел в мсдн. Это же майкрософтовская функция, а она требует ещё один аргумент (а код для компилятора, который это проверяет, они видимо забыли добавить). Правильно строка будет так выглядеть

    scanf_s("%s",&f, 1024);

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

[[@Dazar](/users/9259/dazar)](/users/9259/dazar) ваша первая основопологающая ошибка в том что вместо строки используете всего один символ

```
...
char f;
...
```

надо испольвать именно строку, например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     char  s[255];
     cin.getline(s, 255);
     cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно как на c++ должно быть

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string s;
     cin >> s;
     cout << s;
}
```

Читает до 1 пробельного символа.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;
  int main(){
     cout<<"write smth:";
     string s;
     getline (cin,s);
     cout<<"u typed:"<<s;
  }
```

Еще один вариант решения задачи

Answer (score -1):

Или еще так на C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{ 
char f[80]; 
cout<<"Vvedite stroku"; 
gets(f); 
cout<<"Stroka";
cout<<f;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да что за странный язык с тонной способов ввода/вывода><

Comment: В этом вся прелесть)

Comment: >Да что за странный язык с тонной способов ввода/вывода><

gets - это наследство от Си. Не забывайте, что послужило основой для крестов

Comment: >В этом вся прелесть)

я ва  уверяю, прелесть C++ даже близко не в этом

Comment: А вот функцию `gets()` использовать не рекомендуется. 

Невозможно обезопасить себя от переполнения буфера.

Answer (score -2):

```
Строка это String
string S;
А вы пишете Char
char S;
```

Comment: надо же как интересно